# Java + Android: аварийная остановка приложения при использовании findViewById

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

В процессе локализации ошибки установил, что приложение "летит" на строке с методом `findViewById` (я убрал из кода всё лишнее, у меня же на данный момент всё, что я не вставил сюда, закомментировано):

```
public class AddItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
    }

    LinearLayout AddItemContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AddItemContainer);
}
```

Странно, что раньше всё прекрасно работало, причем эту строку я с тех пор не трогал. В чём может быть причина?

(В данную активность мы попадаем из другой активности; это тоже работает нормально, если убрать строку с `findViewById`).

---

*Обновление*

- Вырезка из сообщения об ошибке:

  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: какая ошибка? проверь существование AddItemContainer и activity_add_item

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке опубликовал. AddItemContainer я скопировал из XML, так что ошибки быть не может. activity_add_item тоже точно существует, иначе разметка не отображалась бы с закомментированной строкой с findViewById.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод findViewById нельзя вызывать до метода onCreate, и бессмысленно до setContentView. А у вас он используется для инициализации поля, то есть вызывается ещё даже до конструктора... На этот момент в активити ещё ничего не проинициализировано, она знать не знает ничего ни о каких вьюхах.

Comment: С точки зрения кода, findViewById как раз вызывается после  onCreate... Это значит, код после OnCreate выполняется раньше?

Comment: Вызывается он при инициализации поля класса, инициализация полей класса происходит при создании экземпляра класса перед вызовом его конструктора. И всё это происходит задолго до вызова метода onCreate. То что вы поле описали ниже описания метода совершенно ни на что не влияет, разве что раздражает тех кто привык читать код написанный по общепринятым правилам, где в частности поля всегда описываются перед методами. В общем учите основы явы...

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю Вас за ответ, теперь данная ошибка устранена. Но что, если мне нужна переменная AddItemContainer в нескольких вспомогательных методах за пределами OnCreate? (Нужна была бы только в одном - можно было бы объявить переменную в этом методе, но их несколько).

Comment: ну объявляете поле в описании класса, а присваиваете значение внутри onCreate. Усё, после этого можно использовать её значение где угодно)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Теперь всё замечательно! :)