# Android&Java: условие возникновения ошибки при использовании findViewById

Tags: java, android, activity, activity-life-cycle

Этот вопрос является развитием темы 
[Java + Android: аварийная остановка приложения при использовании findViewById](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565157/java-android-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-findviewbyid). Из ответа на данный вопрос я узнал, что метод `findViewById` нельзя использовать до метода `onCreate`, и, с точки зрения последовательности кода, и вне метода onCreate (цитирую ответ):

> Метод findViewById нельзя вызывать до метода onCreate, и бессмысленно
>   до setContentView. А у вас он используется для инициализации поля, то
>   есть вызывается ещё даже до конструктора... На этот момент в активити
>   ещё ничего не проинициализировано, она знать не знает ничего ни о
>   каких вьюхах.

Вот мой ошибочный код из того вопроса:

```
public class AddItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
    }

    LinearLayout AddItemContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AddItemContainer);
}
```

Тем не менее, в шаблоне Android Studio метод `findViewById` встречается dyt `onCreate` в методах `onBackPressed()` и `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. Почему это не вызывает ошибки?

```
package jp.co.wajyouhougijyutsu.yd.myapplication2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Порядок вызова методов при инициализации активити таков:

1. Инициализируются статические переменные и выполняются блоки статической инициализации.
2. Выполняется конструктор (для активити и фрагментов он жестко завязан на систему - не трогайте его никогда)
3. Выполняется onCreate метод
4. Внутри onCreate() вызывается реализация этого метода в супер-классе.
5. Только теперь можно вызвать `setContentView` и загрузить разметку.
6. Теперь можно обращаться к разметке - она загружена. Все последующие методы жизненного цикла также имеют к ней доступ.

При этом ваши собственноручно созжанные методы следуют тому же правилу - если вы создадите метод, в котором будете обращаться к разметке то он безошибочно отработает при его вызове в `onCreate` после `setContentView` но вызовет ошибку, если его вызвать до этого момента

Answer (score 6):

Потому что перечисленные Вами методы вызываются **после** вызова `onCreate(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Если пользователь своими действиями вызовет `onBackPressed()` или `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` это не вызовет ошибки, т.к на этот момент `onCreate` отработает и разметка будет отрисована.